# Hall sensor for electric(!) field?

Tags: electric-fields, measurements, hall-effect

Is it (in principle) possible to measure the strength of an electic(!) field with a hall sensor?

I think so, for the following reasons:

1. The hall sensor is a conductor. If we place an conductor in an electic field, charges will rearrange so that there will be no electric field in the interior of the conductor (~Faraday's cage).
2. The field that is created by the new charge distribution in the hall sensor is opposite to the surrounding field, but has the same strength.
3. Following the usual argumentation, we get a voltage across the hall sensor that is proportional to the field inside the hall sensor, which has the same strength as the surrounding field that we want to measure.

Is this line of thought correct? If so, what are technical difficulties that make the hall effect not suitable to measure electric fields?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you do not actually consider a Hallsensor wich needs current flowing trough, but just a conducting sheet put in an electric field measuring the  difference between two sides. But first the sheet will disturb the field, and second how will you measure it without a closed circuit of some kind?

Answer (score 0):

The only suggestion that I have seen for measuring an electric field (like the one at the surface of the earth) is to look at the AC output from a  small, rapidly rotating, dipole antenna. An un-powered DC circuit goes quickly to zero current, field, and voltage difference.

Comment: But wouldn't it in principle be possible to measure a voltage across the hall sensor (or any conducting object) in the electric field?

Comment: The field you are trying to measure would also act in the wires connected to your meter.

Comment: Would this make measurement impossible or just harder?